# Can't get full url of Image Field Django Rest

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two serializers:

```
class AlbumImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    url = serializers.SerializerMethodField('get_url')

    def get_url(self, obj):
        return obj.image.url

    class Meta:
        model = AlbumImage
        fields = ['id', 'url']

class PhotoAlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photos = AlbumImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PhotoAlbum
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'photos')
```

And i read that to display full url of image it's enough to pass a request context to serializer call, like:

```
serialized = SomeSerializer(some, context={"request": request})
```

And when you use `ViewSet` you don't need to do anything, DRF will automatically pass the request context while initializing the serializer.

I am using ViewSets like:

```
class PhotoAlbumViewSet(mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                        mixins.ListModelMixin,
                        GenericViewSet):
    serializer_class = PhotoAlbumSerializer
```

but still my get-request returns response like:

```
"url": "/media/images/photo.jpg"
```

How can i get

```
"url": "127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/photo.jpg"
```

In my case?

My models

```
class PhotoAlbum(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, auto_created=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Pet name')

class AlbumImage(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, auto_created=True)
    album = models.ForeignKey(PhotoAlbum, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='photos')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100, blank=True)
```

Another endpoint where print `url` return the response like `127.0.0.1:8000/media/UUID/photo.jpg`:

```
@action(methods=['post'], detail=True)
def photo(self, request, pk):
    file = request.data['file']
    album = PhotoAlbum.objects.get(pk=pk)
    alb_img = AlbumImage(album=album, image=file)
    alb_img.save()
    return Response({'id': pk,
                     'url': alb_img.image)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do not try to override the url field, let the framework take care of it for you:

serializers.py

```
class AlbumImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.AlbumImage
        fields = ['id', 'url']

class PhotoAlbumSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    photos = AlbumImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = models.Pet
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'photos')
```

sample output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Pet name.",
        "photos": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/media/random_image_one.png"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "url": "http://localhost:8000/media/random_image_two.png"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Doesn't work, exception :(

Comment: What kind of exception, also could you add your models to the question?

Comment: Exception, that serializer doesn't know anything about `url`. Okay, i will add in a few minutes

Comment: Because there is no `url` attribute in your model, it is called `image`. So, change `AlbumImageSerializer` fields to: `fields = ['id', 'image']`

Comment: Can i ask you one more question? When i doing this in the `post` method and create the `alb_img = AlbumImage(album=album, image=file)`, when i use `print(alb_img.image)` it prints the url like: `http://localhost:8000/media/UUID/random_image_two.png`, is there any options to print it without `UUID`?

Comment: Is that another `endpoint` for creating images? I am a little bit confused, in any case, you should be using a serializer to create objects e.g. `MySerializer(request.data)`. If you can add your view to the question I can give a more concrete answer.

Comment: Yes, it's another endpoint, i added this to the question

Comment: Sorry for the late response. That is a bit odd, it should print only the file name. In any case you can use the request to build it: `url = request.build_absolute_uri(alb_img.image.url)` then `return Response({'id': pk, 'url': url})`. Although, I should point out once again that you should use `AlbumImageSerializer` to validate data before saving it.

Comment: Thanks, yes, i already found this solution with `build_absolute_uri`, but it's just interesting why the serializer itself displays the address correctly, and in this case it adds an id

Comment: In a shallow explanation, its because `'id'` is listed in fields and the form how DRF works with `models.ImageField`. Of course, if you are interested in going deeper, you can always explore `serializers.ModelSerializer` code by pressing cmd (or crtl) + left click.  :)

Answer (score 1):

you only have to pass **request** object to your serializer

```
serializer = ReviewSerializer(data=data, context={'request': request})
```

and you will get
[image]